# never loggout admin magento

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

i want to make magento admin never logout in my computer. I have tried increasing cookies life time and other thing. But never got successed.

Is there any other way to edit code and make never logout the admin side?
if so, please help me. Thanks

Comment: In your local.xml, what storage engine are you using for session?

Comment: i have set it as "files", not DB..

Answer (score 4):

Just note - doing this would be a complete breach of PCI regulations.

> 8.1.8 If a session has been idle for more than 15 minutes, require the user to re-
>   authenticate to re-activate the terminal or session.

See https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/Prioritized_Approach_for_PCI_DSS_v3_.pdf

---

You would need to increase the session timeout for the [admin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/51357/361) and if using file based sessions also change your PHP cron session clean-up to suit.

On most platforms the cron obtains the value from `/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime` - which parses in the PHP ini files.

Answer (score 3):

Although I would not recommend doing this, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes?lq=1

> session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of
>   seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and cleaned up.
>   Garbage collection occurs during session start.

You can set this value in either php.ini or your .htaccess file

Answer (score 2):

First of all: I cannot recommend having a setting where you never log out of an admin session. That is a security risk (just imagine you log in on a 3rd party PC and forget to log out) and far away from best practise.

**Increasing the value**

Increase the session lifetime for admin cookies here:

System > Configuration > Admin > Security > Session Lifetime (seconds).

The value is defined in seconds, so if you want to extend that time, you have to multiply it with 60 (for example: setting it to 7200 will result in 120 minutes: 7200 / 60 = 120 minutes).

> Values less than 60 are ignored. Note that changes will apply after
>   logout.

Apart from this (as already mentioned in the answers above), it is also necessary that you adjust your file storage settings for your session files.